# NSMutableArray retain count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
    target_locations[ 0] = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude :  51.50373056 
                                                      longitude :  0.129986111];
   [target_locations[ 0] release];
```

Consider the above code, is it the proper way to keep the assigned object to have a retain count of 1 ?

*Assuming ARC is not activated.

Comment: The answer depends on what type `target_locations` is (although you shouldn't _really_ be sending `release` to the object in the array either way). `NSArray` or plain-C array?

Comment: Think *owhnership*, not *retain count*. Or, if you have to, don't let @bbum know.

Comment: target_locations is a NSArray, hope bbum would make a comment ... :)

Comment: Sorry I'd made a mistake, target_locations[] is a plain-C array.  But I think Julius's answer still applies.

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `target_locations` is an `NSMutableArray`, and that ARC is not enabled, the correct procedure here is as follows:

```
CLLocation * newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude :  51.50373056 
                                                      longitude :  0.129986111];
target_locations[0] = newLocation;
[newLocation release];
```

You shouldn't send `release` to the result of an array access because you don't own that object *through that pointer*. While it does work *in this case*, it's incorrect semantically and too likely to cause problems if you get into the habit.

Also, consider renaming `target_locations` to `targetLocations`, which is consistent with Cocoa style. Using the underscore makes it look like a plain-C array rather than an object.